# Vi, replace text

Tags: replace, vi

I have text like this

```
template
template
template_results
template
```

And I need to replace it to this

```
template_form
template_form
template_results
template_form
```

How can I replace every match of `template` that is not followed by `_` character in Vi?

I tried it like this

```
:%s/template[^_]/template_form    - Pattern not found
:%s/template\[^_]/template_form   - Pattern not found
:%s/template[_]/template_form     - This works, but the pattern is opposite of what I need
```

Thank you :)

Comment: GregHNZ provides the complete answer. You could also match against `template[^_]*`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use negative lookahead:

```
:%s/template\(_\)\@!/template_form/gc
```

This means match any "template" not followed (`\@!`) by any "_"

See: `:help /zero-width`

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to specify template then nothing.
So the trick is to use the end of line specifier `$`

```
:%s/template$/template_form/g
```

The first one doesn't work because this `[^_]` matches any single character other than underline, but not no characters (or end of line, apparently).

Comment: actually, I have variable that I need to rename, and it can be followed by other commands, like
`$template->SetTag();` or `$template = new TEMPLATE;`
So I cant use "end of line specifier"

Answer (score 0):

This is easy in VIM, but sticking to what I BELIEVE to be in vanilla VI, you could do

```
:%s/template$/template_form/
```

This assumes that each line is followed by a end-of-line.  If not, try:

```
:s/template\(\s\|$\)/template_form/
```

I don't know if the "magic" is right for your flavor of VI, but this matches "template" followed by whitespace or the end-of-line.